# does qfixj overrides value of tag 43

Tags: java, quickfixj

If I explicitly add tag 43=N in a message, will qfixj replace it with Y when the same message is re-sent for some reason?

if yes then is there a way to tell qfixj to not include/replace this tag on re-sending any particular message? i do not want to do it myself in the toApp callback as this would cost performance because I only want this tag set to N for just one particular message type.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a header field used for transport-layer control, so yes, the engine will set it accordingly.

The behavior you're asking for is pretty non-standard.  If you want to catch it and override it, your only options are to use `toApp` or hack the engine's source.